# Geolocation API handling on iOS Shortcuts

Tags: ios, geolocation, shortcut

I am working on a simple project to use MAC address based Google geolocation API.

I've been writing similar web based JSON projects more than 20 but, this one, I couldn't make it work on Shortcuts on iOS.   It works fine on curl as Google curl sample code described in [Geolocation API - Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) but, rewriting code in IOS Shortcuts returns "not Found" error.    Does anybody has experience to use WiFi Mac address geolocation API on Shortcuts?

The curl script for geolocation is pretty simple.

```
curl -d @test.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=[MY_API_KEY]
```

and `test.json` contains sample data from google sample page as following contents.

---- test.json starts here-----

```
{
    "considerIp": "false",
    "wifiAccessPoints": [
    {
        "macAddress": "00:25:9c:cf:1c:ac",
        "signalStrength": -43,
        "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
    },
    {
        "macAddress": "00:25:9c:cf:1c:ad",
        "signalStrength": -55,
        "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

---- test.json ends here-----

and here is my code in Shortcuts.

[image: Shortcuts code]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7SEV.png)Well, after few hours of trying, I found one way to obtain coordinates.   I know it is not a smart way but, using "File" in the request body just like curl returned right coordinates.   Right answer is (33.3632..., -117.0872...)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi63y.png)